# Store images on temporary table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, filestream

I'm trying to store/pull some images on a temporary table on SQL Server 2012.

For example, a user drops/creates a QR code for an invoice on

> C:\InvoiceImg

The image is called

> QR_312784.jpeg

I would like to "pull" or store this image in SQL Server 2012 and then reference it with an invoice number so I can use it on a custom report with SSRS.

Is this possible?

Comment: Whether the Image is stored in a Temp table or in any other table as long as your data set query can access it , you should be able to pull the image at run time.

Comment: I suggest you use filestream. Also why would it need to be a 'temp' table? Why not store it permanently? SSRS doesn't play well with temp tables: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2978/rendering-images-from-a-database-on-ssrs-reports/

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT identity,img IMAGE)
DECLARE @pic VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @pic=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\InvoiceImg\QR_312784.jpeg ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS pic)
INSERT INTO #temp(img) VALUES(@pic)
SELECT * FROM #temp
```